# Grocery Crud set relation between 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, foreign-keys, grocery-crud

I have 3 sql tables and they are with this form.

**TEST**

- test_id
- test_name

**EXAMPLE**

- example_id
- example_test_id

**SOMETHING**

- something_id
- something_example_id

So i want to take the name of the TEST table among with the id 
and send it to the table EXAMPLE, and then the example_id should be sent to SOMETHING table.
Finishing the relation i want the name of the TEST table to be shown by the example_id in the SOMETHING table.

We have tried this

```
 $crud->set_relation_n_n('something','example','test','example_id','example_test_id','test_name');
```

And it takes the id of the TEST and it saves it to example_test_id but we want it to be saved at something_example_id and show the test_name.
All the tables have foreign keys and primary keys.
Hope you understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier for you if you were using custom model functions instead of set_relation_n_n function.

First create a model function to get all the id and test_id from example table

```
public function get_example_list()
    {
        $this->db->select('example_id, example_test_id');
        $this->db->order_by('example_id asc');
        return $this->db->get('example')->result();
    }
```

Next, create a second model function to get tha test_name using the test_id from the first model

```
public function get_test_names($id)
    {
        $this->db->select('test_name');
        $this->db->from('test');
        $this->db->where('test_id', $id);
        $name=$this->db->get();
        return $name->row()->test_name; 
    }
```

in your controller use the above functions to create an array with the data you need

```
$list = $this->your_model->get_example_list();

        foreach ($list as $column => $data) {
            $myarray[$data->example_id] = $this->your_model->get_test_names($data->example_test_id);
        }
```

finally use "field_type" function to pass the array into something_example_id.

```
$crud->field_type('something_example_id','dropdown',$myarray);
```

Now. in something_example_id column you have a dropdown, displaying the test_name value and saving the example_id value on your database.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need separate drop-downs, you can create DB view on example table:

```
create view_example as
  select example.*, test.test_name as test_name
  from example left outer join test on 
    example.example_test_id = test.test_id
```

and then in your controller for table something_example_id:

```
$crud->set_primary_key('example_id','view_example');
$crud->set_relation('something_example_id', 'view_example', '{test_name}.{example_id}');
```